# Setting up multi css file for diffrent media in wp_enqueue_style

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have design a emplate with unique css file for each media. my css files are :

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/css/minitablet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px)">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/css/tablet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px)">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/css/windows.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1350px)">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/font/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

now I want use wp_enqueue_style for all this stylesheet but I can't setup media page size and my style sheet didn't load for mobile, tablet , and...
I used wp_enqueue_style like this:

```
 wp_enqueue_style( 'mainstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',false,'1.1','all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'mainstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mobile.css',false,'1.1','screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 576px)');
```

is it wrong way? how should I include my media css file to WordPress theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked this on a test site and is working

```
 wp_enqueue_style('test-css',get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/mob.css',array(),false,'screen and (max-width: 800px)');
```

Try adding the default values for dependency and version.

Comment: thanks for your reply. it's working. my Media Query was true too. but I had some other problems that I have solved.

Comment: Okay anyway , nice to hear that your problem got solved .